# Why I cannot compile? If errorlevel 1 goto stop ; link /co

Tags: assembly, masm

I spend whole evening trying to figure out the error Mr. Compiler is giving me.

It says

```
0 Warning Errors
0 Severe Errors

...if errorlevel 1 goto stop

...link /co asciihexNew,,,console;
```

I kept looking for an answer but there is not a lot of material online available regarding MASM.
This is my code

```
page  55,80

.model small
.stack 100h

.data

msg1 db  0DH,0AH, "Enter the any key",0DH,0AH,"$" ; this is a alphanumeric variable
num db 0   ; this is a numeric variable

.code

main proc
    mov   ax,@data       ; set up data segment
    mov   ds,ax
mainloop:
    MOV NUM, 0  
    mov   dx,offset msg1 ; dx gets the location of the variable msg1
    call string_display     ; calls string_display procedure
    call keyin          ;calls keyin procedure

    mov num, al ; saving the first number
    MOV BL, 8

    MOV DL, 3DH  ; DISPLAY THE = SIGN, it has value 3D in hexadecimal , according to ASCII table
    CALL DISPLAY    ; calls procedure DISPLAY

loop1:
     RCL num, 1     ; Rotate Left with Carry Flag by 1 bit
         JNC DISPLAY0         
          MOV DL, 31H
     call display
     DEC BL
     JZ Hex_disp
    JMP LOOP1
DISPLAY0:

         MOV DL, 30H
    call display    
    DEC BL
     JZ Hex_disp
    JMP LOOP1

Hex_disp:
    RCL NUM, 1
    MOV DL, 3DH
    call display    
    MOV BL, NUM
    SHR BL,1
    SHR BL,1
    SHR BL,1
    SHR BL,1

    AND BL,0FH
    MOV DL, BL
    ADD DL, 30H
    call display    
    MOV BL, NUM
    AND BL, 0FH
    MOV DL, BL
    ADD DL, 30H
    CMP DL, 3AH
        JNS ABC
    call display    
    mov dl, 68h
    call display
    JMP MAINLOOP
ABC:
    ADD DL, 7; (dISPLAY HEX CHR)
        CALL DISPLAY    
    mov dl, 68h ; DISPLAY H
    call display
    JMP MAINLOOP
    mov   ax,4C00h       ; return to DOS and terminate the program
     int   21h


display proc ; display of a single character
    mov ah, 6
    int 21h
    ret
    display endp

keyin proc
    mov ah, 1 ; getting a key from the keyboard 
    int 21h 
    ret
keyin endp

string_display proc
    mov   ah,9           ; send message string to the screen
            int   21h 
    ret
string_display endp


main endp
end  main
```

If you know how to fix it please write a post! Thank you!

Comment: Your code works (tested). Did you start it from a console? Did you eventually confuse 16-bit and 32-bit MASM? Please show at least the source of the batch file (`.bat` or `.cmd`) which output you posted first.

Comment: For a 16 bit executable using MASM we need a 16 bit linker.[link]http://download.microsoft.com/download/vc15/Update/1/WIN98/EN-US/Lnk563.exe[/link]. This file includes the linker version 5.60 for to generate 16-bit DOS applications.

Comment: I changed the linker to recommended by Dirk Wolfgang Glomp. However I started getting extra line in the error:
fatal error 1093: object file not found
So I brought back the original linker. It still gives me the same original error but this time at least outputs file that works. It is really weird but at least it works.Before it wasn't creating any file.

Comment: Seems like the problem was the file name and its length. It was 9 characters and when I changed it to 6 characters then it spit out compiled file.

Comment: Thanks for feedback and have a nice day. Sounds like thread can be close, problem solved.